# Adding property to mulitple documents in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this data structure:

```
{
  "_id": "5ebd08794bcc8d2fd893f4a7",
  "username": "johan@gmail.com",
  "password": "123",
  "decks": [{
      "cards": [{
          "_id": "5ebd08794bcc8d2fd893f4a9",
          "planeetnaam": "Venus",
          "kleur": "Grijs"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5ebd08794bcc8d2fd893f4aa",
          "planeetnaam": "Neptunus",
          "kleur": "Paars"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "5ebd08794bcc8d2fd893f4a8",
      "name": "Planeten"
    },
    {
      "cards": [{
          "_id": "5ebd08794bcc8d2fd893f4ac",
          "diernaam": "Hond",
          "poten": "4"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5ebd08794bcc8d2fd893f4ad",
          "diernaam": "Kangoeroe",
          "poten": "2"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "5ebd08794bcc8d2fd893f4ab",
      "name": "Dieren"
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

Now i want to add a new property to all the cards in deck with deckname: "Planeten". How do i do this with a mongoose query?
The cards array of deck "Planeten" should look like this after the query

```
"cards": [{
    "_id": "5ebd08794bcc8d2fd893f4a9",
    "planeetnaam": "Venus",
    "kleur": "Grijs",
    "newProp": null
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ebd08794bcc8d2fd893f4aa",
    "planeetnaam": "Neptunus",
    "kleur": "Paars",
    "newProp": null
  }
],
```

EDIT:
This works in Robo3T:

```
db.getCollection('users').findOneAndUpdate(
    { '_id': ObjectId("5eba9ee0abfaf237f81fb104") },
    { $set: { 'decks.$[deck].cards.$[].newProp': null }  },
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'deck._id': ObjectId("5eba9ee0abfaf237f81fb108")  }  ]  }
 )
```

But the server query doesnt edit any data:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { '_id': req.session.userid },
        { $set: { 'decks.$[deck].cards.$[].newProp': null }  },
        { arrayFilters: [{ 'deck._id': req.params.deckid  }  ] }, function(err, user){
            res.send('test');
        })
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [array update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/)

the query may look something like that

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { _id: <ObjectId> }, // the filter part
    { $set: { 'decks.$[deck].cards.$[].newProp': null } },
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'deck.name': 'Planeten' }] }
)
```

`$[deck]` refers to each element in the decks array

`$[]` is used to update all the elements in the cards array

your function may look something like that

```
User.updateOne(
    { '_id': req.session.userid },
    { $set: { 'decks.$[deck].cards.$[].newProp': null } },
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'deck.name': 'Planeten' }] })
    .then(function (user) {
        if (!user) {
            res.status(404).send('Er ging helaas iets fout')
        } else {
            res.status(201).send("Card is toegevoegd");
        }
    })
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this gives me the following error: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]

Comment: I've update my answer, could you check it? could you try this `{ arrayFilters: [{ 'deck.name': 'Planeten' }], new: true }` instead of `{ arrayFilters: [{ 'deck.name': 'Planeten' }] },
    { new: true }`?

Comment: Yea i got rid of the error but it doesnt change any data :(

Comment: what is in req.session.userid and req.params.deckid?, could you log them?

Comment: the correct Id's, i have mutiple end-points on the server that do work so the id's are not the problem i believe.
I updated my post so the code is easier to read because i got it working in Robo3T

Comment: also could you try to find the user first then log it? try this `User.findOne({ _id: req.session.userid }), function(err, user) { console.log(user) })`, then check the result of that query

Comment: No results with making it a promise.
This is the result for the query above:
```
{ _id: 5ebd08794bcc8d2fd893f4a7,
  username: 'johan@gmail.com',
  password: '123',
  decks:
   [ { cards: [Array],
       _id: 5ebd08794bcc8d2fd893f4a8,
       name: 'Planeten' },
     { cards: [Array], _id: 5ebd08794bcc8d2fd893f4ab, name: 'Dieren' } ],
  __v: 0 }
```

Comment: I feel like we are so close because it works in Robo3T?! but i just dont understand why the same doesnt work in the server

Comment: do you need to just update the record in db? or you need to update and retrieve the data after update?

Comment: also, If it's possible, could you share the github repository, so I can check it more, If that's possible

Comment: Just update, unfortunately i cant share the repo. its my schools and i cant change the settings.

Comment: okay sure, no worries, could you try this `User.updateOne(
        { '_id': req.session.userid },
        { $set: { 'decks.$[deck].cards.$[].newProp': null } },
        { arrayFilters: [{ 'deck.name': 'Planeten' }] })
        .then(function (user) {
            if (!user) {
                res.status(404).send('Er ging helaas iets fout')
            } else {
                res.status(201).send("Card is toegevoegd");
            }
        })`

Comment: Yes this works! but now ofcourse only for the deck that has name "Planeten". So can i replace the name with id ? but i think we tried that already right ?

Comment: great :), how do you mean by replacing the name with id?, do you want to depend on id to update the array items?, if yes, which id?

Comment: Yes it works now. i did replace name with id and it works finally! EDIT sorry i just saw that in my example i did it based on deck.name thats my fault should be id but it works either way so thanks for helping me out man!

Comment: Btw do you might now how i can replace 'newProp' with a variable ? so i can create the new property bases on user input ? Something like 'decks.$[deck].cards.$[].${userinput}': null

Comment: yes you can, this is the $set part `{ $set: { [\`decks.$[deck].cards.$[].${userInput}\`]: null } }`, we warp everything in square brackets, and use the template string to be able to use string interpolation, If you could create a new question, that would be clear in an answer rather than a comment